# Accessing UIViewController from UITableViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

In iOS4, I want to use MPMoviePlayerController.  I have a UIViewController that I pass to a custom class that manages MPMoviePlayerController.  That plays video fine.

I have another view that is a UITableViewController.  Passing the UITableViewController to my UIViewController property on the video class doesn't work.  I just get sound.  I'm fairly sure this is because the UITableViewController needs to be a UIViewController.  I can change the UITableViewController to a UIViewController but this is a fairly good rewrite.  Is there a way to access the parent UIViewController behind the UITableViewController?

I have also tried

```
(UIViewController*)self;
```

but that doesn't work either.  I just get sound again.

Comment: "I have another view that is a UITableViewController." A view controller is not a view, it is a controller... There's a huge difference. A view draws graphics and has a screen position etc. A controller does not. It just helps coordinate activities between the user and a collection of controllers. So maybe you can clarify this a bit? Did you mean a UITableView?

Comment: If you do indeed have a UITableViewController, then that is a subclass of UIViewController, so that should definitely work in your scenario.

Comment: Sorry for not being precise.  I was actually referring to a UIViewController.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `self.parentViewController. From the documentation:

> Parent view controllers are relevant
>   in navigation, tab bar, and modal view
>   controller hierarchies. In each of
>   these hierarchies, the parent is the
>   object responsible for displaying the
>   current view controller. If you are
>   using a view controller as a
>   standalone object—that is, not as part
>   of a view controller hierarchy—the
>   value in this property is nil.

Comment: This video stays in portrait, where as my pure UIViewController does rotate into landscape.  Could this be related to the UITableViewController?

Comment: @4thSpace: I'm not sure how this is related to your original question. Maybe you should post a new question with more specific info?